# Ajax call did not get any response & not able to drop product second time in cart

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento, magento-1.7, jquery-ui-draggable

I want to add products to a cart using drag & drop. In the drop function I call an Ajax function to add products to the cart:

The `url` variable contains the checkout cart URL based on the product.

```
jQuery(function() {
jQuery(".category-products" ).accordion();
jQuery(".product-name" ).draggable({
  appendTo: "body",
  helper: "clone"
});
jQuery(".block-content ol" ).droppable({
  activeClass: "ui-state-default",
  hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
  accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    jQuery( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
    var url =  ui.draggable.attr('id');
    jQuery.get(url, function(data) {
          // data is the response from the server..
          if(data.status == 'ERROR'){
    alert(data.message);
    }
          console.log(data); 
      });
         url += 'isAjax/1';
    url = url.replace("checkout/cart","draggableproduct/index");
    try {
        jQuery.ajax( {
            url : url,
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data) { 
                if(jQuery('.block-cart')){
            jQuery('.block-cart').replaceWith(data.sidebar);
        }
        if(jQuery('.header .links')){
            jQuery('.header .links').replaceWith(data.toplink);
        }
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
    }
        jQuery( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );   
  }
}).sortable({
  items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
  sort: function() {
    // gets added unintentionally by droppable interacting with sortable
    // using connectWithSortable fixes this, but doesn't allow you to customize active/hoverClass options
    jQuery( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-default" );
  }
});
});
```

and on indexcontroller code contain:-

```
$this->loadLayout();
                $toplink = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('top.links')->toHtml();
                $sidebar_block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('cart_sidebar');
                Mage::register('referrer_url', $this->_getRefererUrl());
                $sidebar = $sidebar_block->toHtml();
                $response['toplink'] = $toplink;
                $response['sidebar'] = $sidebar;
                                    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
        return ;
```

The product is added to the cart but the Ajax call is not completed as I don't get any response and after dropping 1 product I am not able to drop more products in cart. please help me

Comment: check you browser console for any errors

Comment: What is the URL of the page the javascript function is being called from? What is the URL you are calling? How do you know you didn't get any response? (the code snippet you give doesn't include any handers or callback functions).

Comment: Read the docu - [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Comment: Now I am not getting any error. Basically after dragging one product I am not able to drag any other product. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 jquery.post(url,callback).
```

Answer (score 0):

use success callback.....

> The success callback function is passed the returned data, which will be an XML root element, text string, JavaScript file, or JSON object, depending on the MIME type of the response. It is also passed the text status of the response.

```
jQuery.get(url, function(data) {
   // data is the response from the server..
   console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Now I am getting response but when I check in console then it shows that ajax is not completed yet

Comment: make sure your url is rite..... if you are using firebug console click in the ajax made url and see response if there is any error

Comment: ya I am using firebug console. Url is correct but I am not getting proper response as If url is wrong then product can't be added to cart.

Comment: ok if the url is rite.. try sending reponse....echo somehitng in your url function and send it .. check if u get that in response